# How do I format cells to have the match function work for all numbers in this data set?

Tags: excel, vba, match

Can anyone explain what is happening here? I have some values in column A that I want to use with the match function. But there are some numeric values that don't work with this function, even though they are present in the look up range.

[image]

If I use the "value" formula function in Excel, it still doesn't work. If I copy range "B2:B11" and paste special the values, it still doesn't work. If I erase the calculation and type in by hand the values "244", "246", and "248" the match formula WILL work.

Additionally, if I try to use the match function in VBA and use the "Calculation" column as the first argument, the program will not run. But, if I change the numbers by typing them in by hand, the program will run.

There are no extra spaces. Nothing different that I can see about the cells that do not work.

Does anyone have any ideas for what I can try next?

Comment: Most likely those values aren't exactly 244, 246, and 248... floating-point error maybe.

Comment: What is the exact "Calculation" you're using?  Are your "Raw" values exactly as shown, or is there additional precision hidden by the cell number format?

Comment: The calculation for the first one I type in by hand is : =(D2*100)+1 
And then I copy and paste it to the following rows. 
The raw values come from another spreadsheet, but even if I type those in, the error still happens. I will look up floating-point error.

Comment: Use `ROUND`....https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result

Comment: Yes, that's it! I looked up floating point error and read about ROUND just now. Thank you!!!!!!!!